# Save/load AST and M3 from/to file

Tags: rascal

Creating an AST, or a M3 can take some time depending on the size of the project you are trying to load. So is there a way to store the AST or M3 in a file? So next time you need it, you don't have to create it again since you can just load the complete thing from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write any value from/to disk using [`ValueIO`](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/ValueIO/ValueIO.html), like so:

```
rascal>writeBinaryValueFile(|home:///myFile.txt|, myValue)
ok
rascal>readBinaryValueFile(#myType, |home:///myFile.txt|)
myType: myValue
```

Or in a more readable textual format:

```
rascal>writeTextValueFile(|home:///myFile.txt|, myValue)
ok
rascal>readTextValueFile(#myType, |home:///myFile.txt|)
myType: myValue
```

There also exist JSON and CSV (de)serializers for other formats, to be found in `lang::json::IO` and [`lang::csv::IO`](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/lang/csv/IO/IO.html)

Comment: Where can we find the reference on `|home:///myFile.txt|` format? Particularly, how to pass a path relative to current (project) directory? `home:///` seems to literaly mean OS home directory. `file:///` seems to mean an absolute path...

Comment: @Klesun in Eclipse you can use `project://name/file`

Comment: Hm, thanks, now I noticed the "search path" in the eclipse project tree which hints that `project://` points to the directory one level above the project directory.

Comment: Hmm. Not quite. The name of the project is the authority of the uri and the path relative to the project is the path part of the URI, so the project URI without an authority does not resolve to the workspace